# AWS 100K files upload to S3 bucket from file server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is my requirement :

1. I have a SQL server table which has path for 100K files.
2. I want to rename it to a unique ID, Rename columnname is in the same table.
3. I want to upload these to S3 bucket on AWS
4. Get the Etag number for each file and update it back to the table in different column

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Faster than what?

Answer (score 0):

COuld you please share more info on how are you uploading the files to the s3 bucket at present ? What is the size of the file(s). and where is the source of the files.

Comment: 1)this is a migration task ..so currently all files are located on file shared drives and not uploaded on aws. Client want to move it to AWS cloud,so currently not uploaded any documents.
2) roughly 5-6 MB per file.
3) source is a reqular windows file server

Comment: yes then you can use aws cli to put the files on the s3 bucket.